# XDR on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer-11

In my application, we use the XDR objects (XDomainRequest for IE8 to IE10 and EventSource for other browsers) to open a sticky connection to the server.

However, IE11 doesn't implement the XDomainRequest anymore.

What should I use for IE11? XMLHttpRequest 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN's *Compatibility changes in IE11*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/dev-guides/bg182625(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#legacy-api-additions-changes-and-removals):

> The [XDomainRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288060(v=vs.85).aspx) object is replaced by [CORS for XMLHttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673569(v=vs.85).aspx#cors_xhr).

Comment: @RafaelMaiolla Additionally there's a few EventSource polyfills floating around, they might be worth a look? https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills#eventsource

Comment: This sample is a "GET" sample, what if you absolutely have to POST something? From what i can see so far, IE11 strips the BODY of the POST content so only the headers.

Comment: @ConraddeWet Is it because you need a valid P3P Policy on your server? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21682899/13019