# Failed to get access token from Instagram in jQuery

Tags: javascript, instagram, instagram-api

Here is Postman request and response

[image: screenshot Postman request/response]

I'm trying to get code first from this URL:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id="My ClientID"&redirect_uri='my redirctUri'/&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code&grant_type=authorization_code
```

Then I got code like that: `https://myredirctCode?code=MyCode#_`

Copy that code and paste on Postman collection and getting error

also I'm following [How do I recive instagram log in token using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38433085/how-do-i-recive-instagram-log-in-token-using-ajax) answer to change response type to token

And I'm getting this response

[image: screenshot response]

I'm using Instagram page for displaying.

Comment: It looks like you are sending GET instead of POST parameters there in Postman.

Comment: Hi @CBore,

Thanks for reply.

When I'm getting code then my request is Get , and when get accessToken the Post

Can you please explain which one request you mention?

Comment: Your POST request to `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token` should send the `client_id`, `client_secret`, etc. within the body of the request. You are currently sending them through the query params, which is not what the API expects. See [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions#step-2--exchange-the-code-for-a-token) for details.

Comment: Hi @3limin4t0r,

Thanks for reply,

Men you don't have idea but you save my another day. I'm trying to solving this from since 2 days 

Thanks a lot !