# ServiceStack CORS - No response to OPTIONS request in IE only

Tags: c#, .net, http, servicestack

I have enabled global CORS support in my application

```
        this.Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(
            allowCredentials: true,
            allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Authorization",
            allowedOrigins: "*",
            allowedMethods: "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
        ));

        this.GlobalRequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes, httpDto) =>
        {
            if (httpReq.Verb == "OPTIONS")
            {
                httpRes.EndRequest();
            }
        });
```

In my routes, I have added the OPTIONS verb (probably not necessary)

```
        [Route("/Mailers", "POST, GET, OPTIONS")]
        public class MailersRequest {
            public List<Int64> Properties { get; set; }
        }
```

Everything works great in every browser I've tried except IE 11. The new Edge browser is fine, along with Chrome. On IE 11, the OPTIONS request to /mailers gets no response at all. Here are the Request Headers:

```
Request URL: https://api.blahblah.com:4443/mailers
Request Method: OPTIONS
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Host: api.blahblahblah.com:4443
Origin: https://www.housesellersource.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

The request hangs in a Pending state indefinitely. Again, everything works fine in other browsers.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you don't need to specify a `GlobalRequestFilters` for handling an OPTIONS request, i.e:

```
this.GlobalRequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes, dto) => {
    if (httpReq.Verb == "OPTIONS")
        httpRes.EndRequest();
});
```

Since OPTIONS is already [handled by ServiceStack's CorsFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/18eecd67a66afd1d04d013d3a97cdad962575182/src/ServiceStack/CorsFeature.cs#L96).

But it appears the [issue with CORS in IE is that requires a valid P3P Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21682899/85785).