# Retrieve binary data without using arraybuffer

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following resource:

```
function _arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[ i ]);
    }
    return window.btoa(binary);
}

var API = $resource(server + 'album', {}, {
    get: {
        url: server + 'album/:albumId/photo/:photoId',
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        headers: {
            'AuthToken': 'the secret',
            'Accept': 'image/*'
        },
        interceptor: {
            response: function(resp) {              
                return 'data:'+ resp.headers('Content-Type') + ';base64,' + _arrayBufferToBase64(resp.data)};
            }
        }
    }
});
```

what it does is to receive the binary content of the file from server and return a data uri with the base64 data inside.

I have to say that this call can not be replaced with a simple src tag to the url as there are some authentication headers sent too.

this works fine in newer browsers but I want to keep compatibility with older browsers, so the arraybuffer is a problem here, my question is: is there a way to do all these without arraybuffer?

I tried to remove the response type and convert the string in resp.data using what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240408/reading-bytes-from-a-javascript-string) but no success.

Comment: You might want to check this related question. Some of the answer there might help you get to a solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617720/why-doesnt-the-browser-reuse-the-authorization-headers-after-an-authenticated-x

Comment: you can store binary in a string of you handle the unicode conversion by bit-shifting each char in a loop, much like you use to pack the AB. google "binary ajax" and look for old examples.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Base64_encoding_and_decoding. I haven't tested them, but there are a number of algorithms for converting between arrays of bytes and base64 URI's. In particular the `base64EncArray` function seems to be what you are looking for.