# How to show image with <img> tag but must check header of image URL

Tags: html, web-services

I implemented an API to get Image with Content-Type →image/png.
Some thing like abc.com/photo-back/getimage/?url=hello.jpg
But this API, I check client key from the header to authentication.

so when I use with IMG tag, it cannot load image because cannot pass the header checking.

So are there any way to show image with img tag in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20711569/123297). Fetching the images through `XMLHttpRequest` seems to be the only possible solution if you want to set request headers.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I think the window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent( str ))); is depend on browser. So it very hard when we want to run in devices