# How to get image via AJAX and show via image?

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, base64

I need to get jpeg image from foreign server like

```
http://some.foreign.cdn.server.image.jpeg
```

And render it base64 in image. How could I do it?

Comment: What's wrong with just writing out a `<img src="http://some.foreign.cdn.server.image.jpeg" />`?

Comment: I need to load image into canvas

Comment: In that case, cross-domain browser security restrictions are going to be a severe pain in your ass.

Comment: afaik, canvas from <img> follows the same domain rules that ajax does.

Comment: yes I know. I've found a workaround. I can get binary image via AJAX, translate into base64 and use as data-uri. But how could I translate binary into base64?

Comment: how could I translate binary into base64? fr=new FileReader(); fr.onload=...; fr.readAsDataUrl(blobResponse)

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible without FileReader?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267899/arraybuffer-to-base64-encoded-string

Comment: @Erik: there is also URL.createObjectURL() to get a local-only url that you can feed to an img src

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'll try these :))

Comment: Here's where a cool guy has implemented al your ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617720/why-doesnt-the-browser-reuse-the-authorization-headers-after-an-authenticated-x