# Angular 2 - CORS Nightmare

Tags: angular

I have been through tons of sites/forums to try to find a solution

I thought my server returned the right headers but today I noticed my app was not working in IE (works fine in Chrome)

I get this error

```
Credentials flag was set to true, but Access-Control-Allow-Credentials was not present or was not set to "true".
```

but the http header is clearly sent by my server

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643960/internet-explorer-10-is-ignoring-xmlhttprequest-xhr-withcredentials-true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643960/internet-explorer-10-is-ignoring-xmlhttprequest-xhr-withcredentials-true)

Comment: already tried that one 2 hours ago, does not work

Comment: anybody ????????

Comment: I found out I had to remove the space before : when sending headers in php..... yes, really, I am not joking